# Can I find Ubuntu docker image with all utilities installed as on ubuntu desktop?

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I am looking at the official ubuntu images on dockerhub. https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu?tab=tags

```
TAG
20.04 docker pull ubuntu:20.04 Last pusheda month agobydoijanky DIGEST OS/ARCH COMPRESSED SIZE  7cc0576c7c0e linux/amd64
27.24 MB
```

The problem is that these images are only around 27 MB and don't include essential utilities like sudo and ifconfig. Irrespectively, I am looking for an ubuntu image that comes installed with most of the commonly used packages as on ubuntu desktop/server.

Where can I find one, does ubuntu provide one officially. Else a third party but secure image will also serve my purpose.

Comment: ... just why? The point of docker is to provide only what's needed to run a single service. If that is not your goal, why use docker in the first place? `ifconfig` is also deprecated (and why you'd need that inside a container anyways is beyond me).

Comment: Cross-posted: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1375472/where-can-i-find-ubuntu-docker-image-with-all-utilities-installed-as-on-ubuntu-d

Answer (score 1):

*"Most of the commonly used packages"* is really vague.
What people usually do is create their own image with the tools they need:

For the example you mention, putting this in a file called `Dockerfile` would work:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y install sudo net-tools
```

and run `docker build -t my-own-ubuntu-image .`

You can also use tricks like `rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/`, building using a extra container, ... to shrink the final imagesize.
But judging by your question you don't really care about imagesize so keep it simple.